# Please don't discard me

Tags: riddle, word

I hope you like the simple riddles. Tips would be welcome if they're too obvious :)

```
I often lay beside my kind.

I provide a source of life.

I myself am life.

I often travel great distances.

Please don't discard me.
```

What am I?

Comment: Wow good one! But it's not the answer. You're in the good direction tho ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> a seed?

---

I often lay beside my kind.

> You spread them out when you plant them.

I provide a source of life.

> You get a plant if you sow the seed.

I myself am life.

> It's alive (the embryo?)

I often travel great distances.

> It gets carried by the wind, by animals, etc.

Please don't discard me.

> You could plant it instead of tossing it.

Comment: This is the answer. I intended to have the answer to either be "a fruit" or "a seed". I liked your water suggestion too. It fits the description well :)

Answer (score 2):

> A person (or animal)

fits every line.

*I often lay beside my kind.*

> Well ... use your (dirty?) imagination for this line.

*I provide a source of life.*

> People create/'provide' new living beings (babies).

*I myself am life.*

> People are alive.

*I often travel great distances.*

> Sometimes they go all the way round the world.

*Please don't discard me.*

> Discarding a person does sound like a nasty thing to do!

Comment: +1 Yet again I like the variation of your answers :). I think my riddles are too open to different answers haha :D Oh and uhh, "lay beside" and "lay with". I first wrote "lay with", left that out intentionally to reduce that from happening, but it still did :P